# Starting docker with powershell dev script

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am doing a docker project from scratch, and following a tutorial (I am following the Django2 WebDevelopment Cookbook). I came upon a section, that I don't know how to convert to Powershell from Bash. I have the following script in my `/bin/dev.ps1`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/dev
# environment variables to be defined externally for security
# - MYSQL_USER
# - MYSQL_PASSWORD
# - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
DOMAIN=myproject.local
DJANGO_USE_DEBUG=1 \
DJANGO_USE_DEBUG_TOOLBAR=1 \
SITE_HOST="$DOMAIN" \
MEDIA_HOST="media.$DOMAIN" \
STATIC_HOST="static.$DOMAIN" \
MYSQL_HOST="localhost" \
MYSQL_DATABASE="myproject_db" \
  docker-compose $*
```

I have edited the file to such, since the above wasn't working for Windows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/dev
# environment variables to be defined externally for security
# - MYSQL_USER
# - MYSQL_PASSWORD
# - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
$DOMAIN="myproject.local"
$DJANGO_USE_DEBUG=1 
$DJANGO_USE_DEBUG_TOOLBAR=1 
$SITE_HOST="$DOMAIN" 
$MEDIA_HOST="media.$DOMAIN" 
$STATIC_HOST="static.$DOMAIN" 
$MYSQL_HOST="localhost" 
$MYSQL_DATABASE="myproject_db"
  docker-compose
```

And now it gives me the standard output when you run `docker-compose` without any arguments. I am trying to also run the following from my terminal:

```
MYSQL_USER=myproject_user \
> MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass1234 \
> ./bin/dev up -d
```

Obviously this won't work in Windows, it even gives me an error that it can't find the `MYSQL_USER` command or anything. How do I edit the PS file so that I can use it for Windows? And how do I run it so that it passes the parameters to the file as well?

EDIT: I am perfectly fine if this won't work in Windows and only in Linux, I just need to know if/why it can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some debugging, I changed the powershell script to a .bat file. The contents are as follows:

```
::!/usr/bin/env bash
:: bin/dev
:: environment variables to be defined externally for security
:: - MYSQL_USER
:: - MYSQL_PASSWORD
:: - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
SET DOMAIN=myproject.local

SET DJANGO_USE_DEBUG=1 
SET DJANGO_USE_DEBUG_TOOLBAR=1 
SET SITE_HOST=%DOMAIN% 
SET MEDIA_HOST=media.%DOMAIN% 
SET STATIC_HOST=static.%DOMAIN% 
SET MYSQL_HOST=localhost
SET MYSQL_DATABASE=myproject_db
  docker-compose %*
```

I can run the file normally as described in the tutorial; I need to set the `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` variables, and I do it like this:

```
SET MYSQL_USER=myproject_user & SET MYSQL_PASSWORD & dev up -d
```